# How do I pass arguments to an XNA Game executable?

Tags: xna, c#

How do for example make it possible to pass an argument to the .exe file and read it in my XNA Game?

Examples:

**Enable Editor:**

```
game.exe -devmode
```

**Set Resolution:**

```
game.exe -width 1280 -height 720
```

and in the game check the arguments before starting the game.  I searched for this earlier and thought about it again but found nothing about it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the end of the day, XNA games are just regular .NET applications.

[Read the docs on Main() and args](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

You can also use `System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs` ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx)).

Comment: Yes, I should've thought of that... Just been looking for XNA examples. :)